# I am using Ubuntu and Firefox, why every website is using dark mode for me? I didn't enable it anywhere, how do I disable this?

Tags: 20.04, firefox

Twitter, Google they are all dark. How to disable it? In OS or in browser? I use a standard appearance theme in Ubuntu (not light and not dark).

I would like everything to be light, as it used to be.

```
Name                     Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher     Notes
bare                     1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓    base
core                     16-2.54.3                   12725  latest/stable    canonical✓    core
core18                   20211215                    2284   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
core20                   20220215                    1361   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
gimp                     2.10.28                     383    latest/stable    snapcrafters  -
gnome-3-28-1804          3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804          0+git.3556cb3               77     latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
gnome-3-38-2004          0+git.1f9014a               99     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes        0.1-59-g7bca6ae             1519   latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
kde-frameworks-5-core18  5.61.0                      32     latest/stable    kde✓          -
ksnip                    1.9.2                       407    latest/stable    dporobic      -
phpstorm                 2021.3.2                    255    latest/stable    jetbrains✓    classic
snap-store               3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7          558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snapd                    2.54.3                      14978  latest/stable    canonical✓    snapd
```

Comment: Is it only in Firefox or other browsers as well?

Comment: @David only firefox.

Comment: Then it is a Firefox config option look at Firefox support to see what you need to change.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `snap list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try forcing it to light, instead of Auto

[image]